# how to display keys from real time data base into drop down menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[this is firebase pic i want these keys in drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLk7x.png)I only know how to print key on debug console(code given) but I cannot map them with drop down button

```
void fall() async {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await ref.child("/Exam/fall 2022").get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.children.length);
    final examvalue = snapshot.children.forEach((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      print(dataSnapshot.key);
    });
  } else {
    print('No data available.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: ref.child("/Exam/fall 2022").get(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) return Text("Error: ${asyncSnapshot.error}");
    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData) return const CircularProgressIndicator();

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items: asyncSnapshot.data!.children.map((snap) => DropdownMenuItem(value: snap.key, child: Text(snap.key))).toList(),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        ...
      },
    );
  }
),
```

This code is modified from something I needed myself yesterday, but I didn't try to run this exact code. So if you get any syntax or other errors while running this code, please search for the error message first - as it's likely been covered before.